# Wide black stripe on willow trunk

Tags: tree-care, willow

We have a [*Salix alba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_alba) tree of about 45 years old. A couple of years ago there was a fungus growing on the trunk which I removed. This autumn we have noticed a wide black stripe running down the trunk to the ground below where the fungus was growing.

Is this black stripe linked to the fungus and is there anything we can do or is the tree doomed?

Comment: Please add a photo of the trunk.

Comment: Gut feeling: Fungus. Because what you removed was just the fruiting body of the fungus. But please add a photo.

Comment: @Stephie - yeah, probably due to the proximity to the removed fungus (would love to know if it was a shelf fungus), but black streaks can also be slime flux if there's fluid at the top of the streak. Need the photo soon or I'll vote to close.